# Django queryset: equivalent of SELECT all fields from two joined models

Tags: django, django-queryset

There are two models connected with a many to many field

I want to query both and get a de-normalized list of results:

```
class Skills(models.Model):
   skill = CharField(max_length=100)
   ...

class Person(models.Model):
   name = CharField(max_length=100)
   skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills, blank=True)
```

e.g. result object:

```
result.name, result.skill

tom,carpentering
tom,painting
tom,handywork
pete,carpentering
pete,woodwork
```

I would like to have this result in one object. Is there a smart way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

```
results = Person.objects.values('name', 'skills__skill')
for result in results:
    print(result['name'], result['skills__skill'])
```

In this case it's straight forward because the number of fields is small. If there were more fields, then either the code would get very long, or you would need to introspect the field names somehow.

Comment: Using values_list  solved my issue. Thanks for your answer. Although I am only able to access the values with result[0] and result[1]. And "skills__skills'

Comment: There were a couple of mistakes in my answer, which I've fixed now. As you say, it should be `skills__skill` with two underscores. Also, if you use `values` instead of `values_list`, then you can access by attribute name i.e. `result['values_list']`.

Comment: awesome, maybe there are some good reads about the use of "__" in queries and object management  ?

Comment: Here are the docs on using the double underscore for [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). The double underscore is also used for lookups like `__lt` (less than), so reading the entire [making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#making-queries) page might be useful.